# how to get the point when a textbox starts hiding the character on left side in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to get the point when the textbox start hiding the character to the left side
hw is it posible in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You would get the width of the textbox, approximate the width of a char, and when `(char_amounts * char_width > textbox_width)`, you got yourself an overflow.

Comment: its not posible to approximate coz different chars can have different lenght
lik "i" can ..........